# Display xxx on view articles could not be found in Drupal Service View Module

Tags: service, drupal-7

i want to get view response in api using `Service View` but it get not work properly and return response like

```
Display *** on view *** could not be found
```

i have install module `services_views 7.x-1.3` and enabled `view` in `structure\service`

i tried following URL

> http://localhost/mysite/api/views/view_name

but it not work properly

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in other answer you must now specify the display_id when requesting your endpoint. You must also whitelist the view at:

`/admin/structure/services/list/[endpoint machine namn]/view_resource`

or else you will get the error message.

Comment: I did the same you mentioned however, its saying View myrestapi could not be found. Note, I did not include session and OAuth in structure/services. I tried with the following URL: http://localhost/projectName/myrestapi/views/myrestapi?display_id=services_1 but no luck

Comment: I think display_id is the Machine Name of the view

Answer (score 1):

try using the following url :

http://example.com/endpoint_path/views/view_machine_name?display_id=display_id

where you can get the display id by hovering over the display link in your view

hope this helps you